# Sample stored procedure execute from c++ program

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
DBPROCESS *dbconnect(DBPROCESS *dbproc)

int i,count;
char choice;
char num[2];
int page;

int  index;
unsigned long num_recs = 0; 
char db_epass[40], db_user[40], db_pass[40], db_database[60], db_server[40], db_dbname[60];
bool status,valid;

LOGINREC    *loginrec;

int y=ScrWidth/2-10;

count=0;
```

**/I WANT TO EXECUTE STORED PROCEDURE FROM HERE/**

```
dbexit();
```

I'm new to c++ programming, I have the script above where I want to execute a SP with one parameter, passing the information of the 'db_user'.

can anyone guide my how to script it.

Database: mssql 2008

Comment: Have you managed to connect to the database? Which database - the exact calling code will vary between APIs.

Comment: Yes, the script above is the for the login. After this login I just wanted to execute the SP. (Mssql 2008)

Answer (score 0):

to connect to database and execute various `pl/sql` command (including stored procedure call) every vendor provides ODBC driver. In your question it is not clear where you are using the `ODBC driver` in your code and to what database you are trying to connect to. Frist check `ODBC driver` for your database and read vendor provided documentation/manual about how to use their driver with some examples. Every `ODBC driver` `API` are different and codes to execute `pl/sql` will also be different for different vendor provided `ODBC driver` `API`s. Some third party provided `ODBC driver` `API`s are generic for all the different database and you no need to write separate codes for different database, only database connecting string is different. One of them is `datadirect`. Read first vendor provided material on ODBC driver and you will get all the information in it. Wish you all the very best.